# How to update a Bar Chart in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, charts

I want to update my bar chart when the value of the chart get changes.

I get data for the chart from restful services.

I don't want to delete an entire chart and then redraw; instead I wanted to update the existing bar values with the new values.

1.Each and Every time the number of rows is getting changed when i get input from webservice for dataset.
2.I Can manage to update the bars height value when the number of rows is equal.But it contain more number of rows than before i have the problem facing unexpected output.

I submitted the sample code.//i just use this code from stack overflow site.

function mf(){

```
        data = d3.range(10).map(next); 

   var rect= chart.selectAll("rect") 
        .data(data)                         
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; }) 
        .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; }) 
        .attr("width", w) 
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); }); 

rect.enter()
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; }) 
        .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; }) 
        .attr("width", w) 
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); }); 


    rect.exit().remove();

}
```

Comment: There are probably a few dozen examples of bar charts and ways of updating them out there. Can you tell us what specifically you're struggling with?

Comment: Mr.Lars please review my code submitted above and suggest me the solution.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html)?

Comment: Yes Lars. So far i understand from that is updating a chart when the array size is fixed, updating the chart when the dataset1 has more number of element than the dataset2.     All need is what about when dataset1 has less number of element than the dataset2.

Comment: I have submitted a simple code above. please modify that for all posibilities and then submit the complete one.. I need that Lars.

Comment: You need to handle the enter selection in your update function, just like you're doing when initially setting up the chart.

Comment: Lars, i added the .enter().append("rect") but still it doesnt working. I updated the mf() code is above.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please, preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/varadha31590/gG777/

Comment: Your SVG was too narrow to show the new bars: http://jsfiddle.net/gG777/1/

Comment: Oh ! its great Lars.. Thanks for ur Help.... Feel relaxed now only.. Thank u man..